# how to make a ForeignKey Field look like a CharField inspite of ChoiceField in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

By default,`ForeignKeyField` looks like a select box (`ChoiceField`) but I want to make the `ForeignKeyField` look like a `CharField` in my website. In addition, I want to add autocomplete feature on that CharField so that the entries will not disobey the entries in the foreign key field. 
How should I go for it?

Answer (score 0):

Autocompleting is not supported in Django by default, however there are add-on packages available for that purpose. I would suggest [this one,](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/) which supports autocompleting a ForeignKey.